# visual studio 2010 silent crash on unmanaged dll

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, dll, unmanaged

Under Visual Studio 2010 C# application, I'm calling unmanaged dll like this:

```
[DllImport("cyghello.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention =          CallingConvention.StdCall)]
 [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
 public static extern string runMainRoutine(char[] _inputString);
```

C++ dll is build under mingw/cygwin;
Prior this, I had *.exe, it worked fine, then I just changed function to be extern. So it is not dependency problem.

When I call function:

```
string res = runMainRoutine(("balbalbalblalb").ToCharArray());
```

It just silently closes application. No error. No debug info. (Debug unmanaged code is ticked inside Project Options)

What to do? How to understand, what is going on?

I've tried to catch UnhandledExceptionEventHandler, but that did not help.